# É possível impedir notificações para outras aplicações no dispositivo?

Tags: javascript, mobile, notificação

Estou montando meu TCC. É possível implementar no meu app, um bloqueador de outros aplicativos para que não receba notificação enquanto você esta usando o meu app?

Um exemplo básico de como posso retrata isso seria quando você desliga o seu *wi-fi* do seu celular e fica sem internet, você não recebe notificação de nada, como Facebook, Instagram e app como games onlines. Então, quero ter uma maneira de estar com a internet ligada e as notificações desses outros app que listei ali não serem notificadas enquanto estiver utilizando o meu app.

Só o meu app tenha internet pois terá que realizar busca dentro dele.

Se for possível, como? Só preciso de uma direção nada mais.

Comment: Colocar o aplicativo em `full screen` não atenderia o que deseja?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Em condições normais isso não é possível, seria uma falha de segurança tremenda.

Se o **usuário** do celular usar alguma técnica que subverte o sistema operacional para deixar sua aplicação fazer isto, aí tudo é possível, mas quem faria uma bobagem dessas? Obviamente que esta aplicação não estaria em um *store*.

Isso em outra linguagem, em JavaScript é menos possível ainda. Só não digo que é impossível porque no momento que é feito algum trambique no sistema operacional pode dar a capacidade do JS fazer isso, mas na prática ninguém fará isso.

Comment: Eu vou além. No Android, acredito que para permitir isso não basta fazer *root* no dispositivo. Seria necessário escrever uma nova distro do Android. Já no iOS, não é possível de jeito nenhum e acabou.

Comment: @Renan não sei se tanto, mas concordo com a base do que está dizendo. tem que fazer o *root*, e mudar algumas coisas, no é só o *root*, é que sem o *root* nem essas alterações pode fazer. Essa alteração provavelmente interceptaria algo, como é possível fazer nos SOs de desktop que costumam dar liberdade de fazer qualquer coisa se tiver privilégio de administrador.